# Should asking about meaning of a particular excerpt/quote of a book be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Sometimes, I (I think we all do) come across a passage or quote where we couldn't quite understand what author means in that context.

**So, should asking such questions be on-topic?**

Users can get better perspective from others who actually read this.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that some might consider this _off_-topic? I wouldn't normally ask, but this seems to be fairly directly within the scope of the site...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes.

That seems to be exactly what a site for Literature should be for. Literary analysis often involves attempting to understand exactly what an author is trying to say in some particularly obscure passage.

*Some* questions of this form might be better off at [English Language & Usage](http://elu.stackexchange.com) or [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com), though.<sup>1</sup> Before posting your question, you might want to think about whether it's more a language question or a literature question. If you're asking about the meaning of a word or phrase, one of the language sites might be the best place to ask. If you're asking about *what an author was trying to say by* a word or phrase whose meaning you know in general, then definitely ask it here.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Or possibly another language site, if the literary work you're talking about isn't in English. I don't know much about their scopes though.</sub>

Comment: That's good insight, different than what suggested on other question.